# рекурсивный вызов в цикле

Tags: python, функции, циклы, рекурсия, стек

Смотрел ролики Тимофея Хирьянова по алгоритмам и структурам данных. Он использовал рекурсивный вызов внутри цикла, я не понял как.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот объясните пожалуйста, почему у нас например не происходит выхода из рекурсии, когда Х достигается 0, и почему именно такие X выводятся

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score 3):

Нет "выхода из рекурсии". Есть вызов функции и что-то что происходит внутри. Больше ничего нет:

> ```
> f(3)
> ```

> ```
> f(3)
>     print(3)
>     f(2)
>     print(3)
>     f(2)
> ```

> ```
> f(3)
>     print(3)
>     f(2)
>         print(2)
>         f(1)
>         print(2)
>         f(1)
>     print(3)
>     f(2)
>         print(2)
>         f(1)
>         print(2)
>         f(1)
> ```

> ```
> f(3)
>     print(3)
>     f(2)
>         print(2)
>         f(1)
>             print(1)
>             f(0)
>             print(1)
>             f(0)
>         print(2)
>         f(1)
>             print(1)
>             f(0)
>             print(1)
>             f(0)
>     print(3)
>     f(2)
>         print(2)
>         f(1)
>             print(1)
>             f(0)
>             print(1)
>             f(0)
>         print(2)
>         f(1)
>             print(1)
>             f(0)
>             print(1)
>             f(0)
> ```

> ```
>     print(3)
>         print(2)
>             print(1)
>             print(1)
>         print(2)
>             print(1)
>             print(1)
>     print(3)
>         print(2)
>             print(1)
>             print(1)
>         print(2)
>             print(1)
>             print(1)
> ```

Comment: а почему тогда у нас X не становится меньше 1? Я же постоянно вызываю f(x-1)

Comment: Выражение `x - 1` не делает `x` меньше. Оно вычисляет новое число, на единицу меньшее. Это число тоже будет названо `x` но в другом вызове `f`. А другой вызов `f` никак не влияет на текущий вызов `f`.

Comment: спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Если ответ понравился, отметь решением,  это больше чем одно спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Может я попытаюсь пояснить

> Вот объясните пожалуйста, почему у нас например не происходит выхода
> из рекурсии, когда Х достигается 0

Потому что происходит возврат в точку вызова функции, здесь это f(x-1)
и по этому print пишет None, потому что в print(f(3)) ничего не возвращается, но функция не зацикливается, а нормально завершается.

```
def f(x, step_req):
    step_req+=1
    fn=-100
    if x==0:
        print(f'Возврат x={x}')
        return 0
    for i in range(2):
        print(f'Перед вызовом i={i}  Шаг рекурсии {step_req} x={x}')
        fn=f(x - 1, step_req)
        print(f'Точка возврата f()={fn} i={i}  Шаг рекурсии {step_req} x={x}')
print(f(3,0))

Перед вызовом i=0  Шаг рекурсии 1 x=3
Перед вызовом i=0  Шаг рекурсии 2 x=2
Перед вызовом i=0  Шаг рекурсии 3 x=1
Возврат x=0
Точка возврата f()=0 i=0  Шаг рекурсии 3 x=1
Перед вызовом i=1  Шаг рекурсии 3 x=1
Возврат x=0
Точка возврата f()=0 i=1  Шаг рекурсии 3 x=1
Точка возврата f()=None i=0  Шаг рекурсии 2 x=2
Перед вызовом i=1  Шаг рекурсии 2 x=2
Перед вызовом i=0  Шаг рекурсии 3 x=1
Возврат x=0
Точка возврата f()=0 i=0  Шаг рекурсии 3 x=1
Перед вызовом i=1  Шаг рекурсии 3 x=1
Возврат x=0
Точка возврата f()=0 i=1  Шаг рекурсии 3 x=1
Точка возврата f()=None i=1  Шаг рекурсии 2 x=2
Точка возврата f()=None i=0  Шаг рекурсии 1 x=3
Перед вызовом i=1  Шаг рекурсии 1 x=3
Перед вызовом i=0  Шаг рекурсии 2 x=2
Перед вызовом i=0  Шаг рекурсии 3 x=1
Возврат x=0
Точка возврата f()=0 i=0  Шаг рекурсии 3 x=1
Перед вызовом i=1  Шаг рекурсии 3 x=1
Возврат x=0
Точка возврата f()=0 i=1  Шаг рекурсии 3 x=1
Точка возврата f()=None i=0  Шаг рекурсии 2 x=2
Перед вызовом i=1  Шаг рекурсии 2 x=2
Перед вызовом i=0  Шаг рекурсии 3 x=1
Возврат x=0
Точка возврата f()=0 i=0  Шаг рекурсии 3 x=1
Перед вызовом i=1  Шаг рекурсии 3 x=1
Возврат x=0
Точка возврата f()=0 i=1  Шаг рекурсии 3 x=1
Точка возврата f()=None i=1  Шаг рекурсии 2 x=2
Точка возврата f()=None i=1  Шаг рекурсии 1 x=3
None
```